# How do I use A create function that compares 2 tables and does not return an int?

Tags: sql-server, function

I am writing a database for a website for school, in Microsoft SQL Server Express

The database has a lot of different tables and also a lot of primary keys, it is not allowed to change the  table itself.

The problems is that I have 2 tables, `Verkoper` & `Gebruiker`, (sorry the names are in dutch), these are the 2 tables:

```
create table Verkoper (
    Gebruiker char(10) not null,
    Bank char(8) ,
    Bankrekening int,
    Controle_Optie char(10) not null,
    Creditcard char(19)
    constraint pk_Verkoper primary key(Gebruiker),
    constraint fk_Verkoper_Gebruiker foreign key(Gebruiker)
                             references Gebruiker(Gebruikersnaam)
   )

create table gebruiker(
    Gebruikersnaam char(10) not null,
    Voornaam char(10) not null, 
    Achternaam char (15) not null , 
    Adresregel1 char(25) not null, 
    AdresRegel2 char(25),
    Postcode  char(7) not null,
    Plaatsnaam char(25) not null, 
    Land char(15) not null, 
    GeboorteDag char(10) not null,
    Mailbox char(25) not null,
    Wachtwoord char(15)not null, 
    Vraag int not null,
    Antwoordtekst char(20) not null,
    Verkoper char(4) not null, 
    constraint pk_gebruiker primary key(Gebruikersnaam),
    constraint fk_Gebruiker_Vraag foreign key(Vraag) 
                          references Vraag(Vraagnummer)
   )
```

I wanna check if `gebruiker.Verkoper = 'wel'`(yes) or `'niet'`(no). If `gebruiker.verkoper = 'niet'` then you should not be allowed to add it to the verkoper table.
So in short 2 tables gebruiker and verkoper if you wanna add a person to Verkoper, gebruiker.verkoper has to be true.

I already tried to make a function:

```
Create function dbo.checkVerkoper()
RETURNS int         
AS BEGIN RETURN( 
  select count(*) 
   from Verkoper
   inner join gebruiker
    on verkoper.gebruiker = gebruiker.gebruikersnaam
    AND gebruiker.verkoper = 'wel'
 ) 
 END
 go

 alter table verkoper
 add constraint ck_VerkoperGebruiker
 check(dbo.checkVerkoper () = 1 )
```

This does work for 1 person, but if you add more the value will be more then 1, and so the check will be false no one will be add, if you have 4 persons and 3 are not allowed and 1 is then the value is still 1 and you can still add someone to verkoper tabel.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? MySQL? Oracle? ...? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER

Comment: "it is not allowed to change the table itself." - but your proposed solution uses `alter table` - so how is that "allowed" if we're not allowed to change the tables?

Comment: What i ment with not being allowed to change the table is the colums or the column types

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored Procedure
In that

> - Check whether your conditions are met
> - if met, then Do the insert(s)